# Finding a diagonal matrix with restrictions on some value m.

Tags: matrices

Here is:

Just a hint on (0,0,0,) as eigen vector:

> [image]

Comment: By definition, an eigenvector must be non-zero.

Comment: The third eigenvalue is 1, not 7.

Comment: my typo it's 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eigen vector is always non-zero vector (by definition)!
So $(0,0,0)$ as eigen vector will never be the case.
We do this because $T(0,0,0) = T(0(x_1 , x_2 , x_3))$ 
= $0×T(x_1 , x_2 , x_3)$      [as $T$ is linear.]
=$(0,0,0)$